# datatype in for .. next structure

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, types

I ran in a problem with an inadequate type declaration for the counter variable of a for-next loop.

What´s wrong with this code snippet?

```
For n As Byte = 16 to 2 Step -1
    Debug.Print(n)
Next
```

-> The loop is never entered,

while the code

```
For n As SByte = 16 to 2 Step -1
    Debug.Print(n)
Next
```

works as expected.

I´ve been using VB since 1994, currently Visual Studio Community 2019, V16.8.2, but never ran into this problem.
If **n** needs to be of a "signed" datatype when **Step** is of type SByte, Integer ..., to handle neg. numbers, why do I not get an Error, Alert ... from the VS-Compiler?
There is also not hint within the MS doc.

Sure this "problem" can be avoided by using (signed)Byte, Integer, double or decimal as datatypes, but I´d like to understand why VS doesn´t give any alert.
Did I miss something?
Regards
Werner

Comment: What has `Option Strict On` to say about that?

Comment: *I´d like to understand why VS doesn't give any alert. Did I miss something?*: you forgot to set `Option Strict` permanently `On` the first time you run the Visual Studio IDE. Set it `On`, see what the problem is, then - sadly - set it `Off` again, so your Project will at least compile. You'll find out what else is wrong there when the app crashes or *mysteriously* misbehaves.

Comment: As suggested already, `Option Strict` should ALWAYS be `On`, except on the rare occasions that you need to use late binding. Even then, it should be `On` at the project level and set `Off` at the file level in only those files that require late binding. You should also use partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum. No matter how big your project is, you ought to set `Option Strict On` and fix the issues that get flagged because, otherwise, bugs may be lurking that won't show up until run time. Also, set it `On` in the VS options so it is `On` by default in future.

Comment: Option Strict on/off does not affect the behaviour.
What I found out is, unchecking "Remove integer overflow checks" gave the error in Design mode:
BC30439 Constant expression not representable in type 'Byte'
while no error occurred with "Remove integer ..." checked. (both in design-mode and run-time mode, but code inside the loop is never executed)

Seems that the for-loop params Start, End and Step take the Datatype of the loop-counter, as loop-counter never leaves the byte range (0..255)

Comment: The For...Next Statement docs do imply it in the [Counter Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement#BKMK_Counter) section with "The `start`, `end`, and `step` expressions can evaluate to any data type that widens to the type of `counter`." So that you kow the kind of thing to watch for in future.